# JqGrid Size issue when container display:none

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid

I have a jquery grid inside a jquery-ui dialog. Whenever I load the page, the dialog becomes visible for a second before jquery hides it, which looks kind of odd as normally it should not be visible until user clicks the button to show the dialog.

So I tried setting the `display:none` to my container div.

Strangely after that the grid size became 118x118 pixels.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i fixed it.

After initializing the dialog i called

```
$("#mydialog").hide();
```

hope it will help others.